# Textbox lost values after postback in repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control in a user control. The repeater control has a label and a textbox. A new row is added in repeater control on the click of a button. If i add one row and enter some value in textBox and then again add a new row in the repeater control the value entered in the textbox of first row gets lost.

Can anyone help me out how to retain the value of textbox after postback.

Answer (score 4):

You are losing it because you do not have a If not IsPostBack wrapped around the code that sets the value of the textbox.

So every time you execute the page the value is being reset. Wrap the code that sets the value around ispostback and the new value will not be overridden.

> if (!Page.IsPostBack) { // set value }

Answer (score 0):

You may get help from the following **link**:

http://ranafaisal.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/dynamically-adding-removing-textboxes-in-aspnet-repeater/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. i have posted another answer for the above question.

Comment: You other answer is much better, but instead of posting a new answer, you can have just edited this answer with the additional content, by clicking the edit link.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried myself and found a solution:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace RepeaterTest
    {
        public class Car
        {
            private string _year;
            private string _make;
            private string _model;

            public string Year
            {
                get
                {
                    return _year;
                }
                set
                {
                    _year = value;
                }
            }

            public string Make {
                get { return _make; }
                set { _make=value;}
            }

            public string Model
            {
                get { return _model; }
                set { _model = value; }
            }

            public Car(string year,string make,string model){
                _year = year;
                _make = make;
                _model = model;
        }

            public Car(){
        }

        }
    }


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace RepeaterTest
    {
        public class Cars:CollectionBase
        {

            public int Add(Car car) {
                return List.Add(car);
            } 

        }
    }

    in code behind:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace RepeaterTest
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
                    Cars cars = new Cars();
                    Car c1 = new Car("2011", "Marcedez", "Marcedez");
                    Car c2 = new Car("2012", "BMW", "135i");
                   cars.Add(c1);
                   cars.Add(c2);
                    Repeater1.DataSource = cars;
                    Repeater1.DataBind();
                }
            }

            protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "Add") {
                    //Car carLastEntered = new Car();
                    Cars cars = new Cars();
                    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items) {
                        Car car = new Car();
                        car.Year = ((TextBox)(item.FindControl("txtYear"))).Text;
                        car.Make = ((TextBox)(item.FindControl("txtMake"))).Text;
                        car.Model = ((TextBox)(item.FindControl("txtModel"))).Text;
                      cars.Add(car);
                      //carLastEntered = car;

                    }

                    //cars.Add(carLastEntered);
                    Repeater1.DataSource = cars;
                    Repeater1.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    in aspx:
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="RepeaterTest.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
                onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
             <HeaderTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
            <tr style="padding-top: 5px;">
                <td colspan="6">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInstructions" runat="server" Text="Add your cars here:" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="trHeader" style="font-weight: bold;">
                <td>Year</td>
                <td>Make</td>
                <td>Model</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>         
        </HeaderTemplate> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtYear" runat="server" Width="65" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Year")%>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtMake" runat="server" Width="70"             
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Make")%>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtModel" runat="server" Width="70" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Model")%>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate> 
        <FooterTemplate>
            <tr style="padding-top: 5px;">
               <td colspan="6">
                   <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" 
                    Text="Add Car" CommandName="Add" />
               </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.